# Appmaker how to stop a serverside script

Tags: google-app-maker

I've made a serverside script, that is updating my contacts, but it seems the job is working in the background, even if appmaker is closed, how can I stop that job ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a server side script stop unless the script finishes or the time runs out. According to the apps script quotas, the script will run for no more than [30 minutes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations). Hence, all you have to do is wait and one of the two will come first.